# Celery subtask launched from task always pending

Tags: python, celery, celery-task

Why is the status of a subtask launched from a task always in the PENDING state?

```
data = [foo.delay(i) for i in bar]

complete = {}
L = len(data)
cnt = 0
while cnt != L:
    for i in data:
        ID = i.task_id
        try:
            complete[ID]
        except KeyError:
            if i.status == 'SUCCESS':
                complete[ID] = run_hourly.delay(i.result)
                cnt += 1
                if cnt >= L:
                    for ix in complete.values():
                        print ix.status
```

This is obviously a contrived example but the iteration through `data` while checking for task success works fine. But when we iterate through the tasks that we launched in this loop the status of those task remains `PENDING` and they are essentially never executed.

Why is this?

Comment: Some code would be helpful.

Comment: @Banana the print statement will yield 'PENDING' over and over again until I kill the worker

Comment: What does the task do? Since it's called `run_hourly`, maybe it just never gets started?

Comment: task `foo` loads web pages. task `run_hourly` parses them. 'run_hourly' is named as it is because the data it's running is broken into hourly chunks. Eventually there is a 3rd task called that appends the parsed results of `run_hourly` to a .csv file. Then finally when all the pages have been loaded and parsed a 4th task is called to create a table in a db from the created .csv file.